# What are limitations of PostScript 'image' command on HP LaserJet printers?

Tags: postscript

I try to inject hand-crafted PostScript code into larger document generated by pscript5.dll.

I use approach taken from http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/postscript/  (for some *strange* reason, my previous code that was printing 4-bit with single hex character (0..f) using same transformation matrix - stopped working).

So, the sample code is:

```
100 200 translate
26 34 scale
26 34 8 [26 0 0 -34 0 34]
{<
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ff000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef0000ffffffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ce00ffffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00cece00ffffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00cecece00ffffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00cececece00ffff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00000000000000ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efef000000ef000000ef000000ef0000ef0000efefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efef000000ef00000000ef00000000ef000000efefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efef0000ef00000000000000ef000000ef0000efefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff00efefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefefef00ff
ff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
>}
image
showpage
```

---

Following it, taking source image (png) transformed to 1-bit (thus printing each pixel as either '00' or 'FF') on HP LaserJet 1320, I stumbled upon strange problem: after image size reached some value between 128x128 and 300x450, printer prints white rectangle instead of the expected image. Total test document size is 2..9 MB.

Ghostscript-9.07 interpreter shows the larger inserted images properly, however it seems to differ in implementation with HP's embedded interpreter - *it stil works fine with my previous code mentioned above, and the permissiveness of software interpreters is a fact*

**What are possible approaches to solve whitesquaring, besides bruteforcing printer to determine max. printable data size with 'image' approach?**

---

Upd: 300x300 confirmed printable, but random 500x500 image is not printable :(
Linebreaking at 280+ chars - doesn't help.

Comment: try some establised code such as pnmtops.

Answer (score 1):

With very large images you will start to run up against various implementation limits. Common limits are 65535 elements in strings, arrays, and dictionaries. If your image data is larger than 64k, it will need to chopped up into 64k pieces and fed to `image` separately (it is for this purpose that `image` takes a procedure argument rather than just a string data source).

If you are simply embedding the data for a single use, you can use the standard idiom to read-ahead
into a buffer.

```
/buf 100 string
26 34 8 [26 0 0 -34 0 34]
{ currentfile buf readhexstring }
image
%hex data starts here
```

`image` can be considered a looping operator which will keep calling the supplied procedure to get more data. The procedure doesn't even need to return full rows, just little bits of string.